# Assist me in finding the error

Tags: c, pointers, interface, serial-port, embedded

I am working on the interface (RS232) for communication between aeroflex gaisler hardware (RTEMS operating system and leon2 processor) and the desktop terminal. I have written a code for communication between them. I am getting a error in all the function calls, if anyone had experienced this kind of problem then please help me to fix it.

NOTE: This error is different from my previous question.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <ioctl.h>
#include <apbuart.h>
#include <rtems.h>
#include <drvmgr/drvmgr.h>


#ifndef serial_h
    #define serial_h
    #include "serial-com.h"
#endif

//#ifndef read_serial_h
//  #define read_serial_h
//  #include "read-serial.h"
//#endif

#ifndef memory_h
    #define memory_h
    #include "memory.h"
#endif

#define BUFSIZE 500

void readSerialPort(char portname, char tbuffer[8])
{
    char fd;

    // create a new handle for the serial com port
    fd = createSerialPort("portname", DWORD accessdirection); // function call

    // set the configuration of the handle
    setComPortConfig(fd);

    // set the timeout configuration of the handle
    setComPortTimeouts(fd);


    char TBuffer[BUFSIZE];


    sprintf(TBuffer,"%c",tbuffer);


    char nread = strlen(TBuffer);

    readFromSerialPort(fd, TBuffer, nread);
    // read from terminal.
//  // create a new char buffer
//  //char outputBuffer[BUFSIZE];
//  int h1, h2, h3 ;
//
//
//  // copy the two value in the outputbuffer
//  // the ";" is used a delimiter
//  // copy the two value in the outputbuffer
//  // the ";" is used a delimiter
//  sscanf(EF->a,"%d\n",&h1);
//  sscanf(EF->b,"%d",&h2);
//  sscanf(EF->c,"%d\n",&h3);
//
//  // compute the actual size of the output string
//  int nread1 = strlen(EF->a);
//  int nread2 = strlen(EF->b);
//  int nread3 = strlen(EF->c);

    // write the outputBuffer to the serial com port
//  readFromSerialPort(hSerial, EF->a, nread1);
//  readFromSerialPort(hSerial, EF->b, nread2);
//  readFromSerialPort(hSerial, EF->c, nread3);

    // close the handle
    CloseHandle(fd);
}
```

Body of the function:

```
char createSerialPort("portname", DWORD accessdirection)
{
//  HANDLE hSerial = CreateFile(portname,
//          accessdirection,
//          0,
//          0,
//          OPEN_EXISTING,
//          0,
//          0);
    char fd = CreateFile("/dev/rastaio0/apbuart1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE);  // create = open

    if (fd == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        //call GetLastError(); to gain more information
    }

    return hSerial;
}
```

errors like :
    DWORD is not initialized
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE is not initialized
    access direction is not initialized

I have a doubt with respect to function call and the body of function. Give me some ideas.

Comment: How should we know what the problem is, when you don't include the errors you're getting?

Comment: There is something wrong with `fd = createSerialPort("portname", DWORD accessdirection);` line. You should either pass an `accessdirection` parameter (that is, remove `DWORD` and initialize `accessdirection`), or do not use the second parameter at all.

Comment: hi unwind!! now you can see the errors

Comment: @suhassjbit They don't look complete...

Answer (score 4):

Change

`void readSerialPort(char portname, char tbuffer[8])` to `void readSerialPort(char portname, char *tbuffer)`

`char createSerialPort("portname", DWORD accessdirection)` to `char createSerialPort(char *portname, DWORD accessdirection)`

`fd = createSerialPort("portname", DWORD accessdirection);` change to

```
fd = createSerialPort("/dev/rastaio0/apbuart1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE);
```

and then

```
char fd = CreateFile("/dev/rastaio0/apbuart1", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE);
```

to

```
 char fd = CreateFile(portname, accessdirection);
```

This will fix some of your errors.
Regards,
Luka

Answer (score 4):

Define DWORD accessdirection before using it.No need to call accessdirection with its data type.You can call it like following

```
fd = createSerialPort("portname",accessdirection); // function call
```

but this will work only if you have declared `DWORD accessdirection`;

You have not added prototype for char createSerialPort("portname", DWORD accessdirection) function so it is better to define this before its call.

Comment: After considering all the above suggestions , Its throwing errors like :  Generic read undeclared (first used in the function) Generic write undeclared (first used in the function)

Comment: DWORD and GENERIC_READ are specific to windows.You need to add Windows.h in header list.Include winDef.h too.

Comment: Finally I got the solution : #include<fcntl.h>  then it works fine.